# How to find what causes frequent account lock out?

Tags: windows, active-directory

My Active Directory account frequently gets locked out. I'm trying to understand why this happens. I guess I have invalid password somewhere cached on my system

- I have removed all credentials from Windows and Web Credential Managers.
- I have checked whether the problem is not related to failures to map network drives. I've tried `net use` and it shows OK status all network drives.
- My Chrome Web browser has not password cached.

How can I find which process locks me out? Are there any logs to look for?

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: This is a question your should be asking your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm doing that already. I've got some hints from them, but I am also trying to understand myself. For instance, in Ubuntu I can narrow down the moment when the account was locked by grepping syslog for `NT_STATUS_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT` entry. I guess Windows provides similar feature. If my question is too broad, too localized or unclear, feel free to vote for closing it down.

Comment: As it is tagged Active Directory you could enable the corresponding logs for AD. EventID 4740 should be helpful. Beware that there are also separate events for "general" changes to accounts.

Comment: You need first to find out the source of the lockout - see [link](https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-active-directory-lockouts/). See also [this link](https://www.varonis.com/blog/secrets-active-directory-lockouts-find-apps-stale-credentials/) for finding an app that may be using stale credentials.

Comment: Could be any number of programs that you have entered details into. Outlook uses domain credentials, browsers may have cached proxy passwords and so on. Your IT might be able to pinpoint the machine, but have no idea what actual program did it. Rule #1 for domain passwords: the *only* place you put in a password is a box when you log in or unlock the machine. If something asks you out of the blue then either close and reopen the program, or lock and unlock your PC. Both of those refresh credentials between your machine (or program) and the domain. Manual password entry causes this problem.

Comment: I personally use [this microsoft tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15201) to find the location of the lockout and then check the event logs (security - audit failures) on the DC that locked the account to see where it originates from. Usually turns out to be a saved WiFi or webmail password after a user changes their password (and more rarely a service running as their account)